# Sequelize (1 user hasMany posts, 1 post has 1 user, 1 post hasMany evaluation that belongs to a user)

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, associations, evaluate

I'm using Sequelize to create a backend with the tables Users, Pots, and Evaluations.

The user has many posts and each post has many evaluations. I want to get an evaluation to belongs to a post and also a user, but I don't know how I should make this association

My code is on [github](https://github.com/GlaudistonNeto/nodeAPI) but here goes a preview:

model folder:
User.js:

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

class User extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init({
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
      age: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      city: DataTypes.STRING,
      email: DataTypes.STRING,
      password: DataTypes.STRING,
    }, {
      sequelize
    })
  }

  static associate(models) {
    this.hasMany(models.Post, { foreignKey: 'user_id', as: 'posts' });
  }
}

module.exports = User;
```

Post.js:

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

class Post extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init({
      description: DataTypes.STRING,
      image_url: DataTypes.STRING,
      latitude: DataTypes.STRING,
      longitude: DataTypes.STRING,
    }, {
      sequelize
    })
  }

  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'user_id', as: 'owner' });
    this.hasMany(models.Evaluation, { foreignKey: 'post_id', as: 'evaluations' });
  }
}

module.exports = Post;
```

Evaluation.js

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

class Evaluation extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init({
      review: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      rate: DataTypes.DECIMAL(2,1),
    }, {
      sequelize
    })
  }

  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.Post, { foreignKey: 'post_id',  as: 'postage' });
    this.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'user_id',  as: 'owner' });
  }
}

module.exports = Evaluation;
```

The Evaluation.js is only being associated with the post, not also with the owner of the post

Answer (score 0):

Forget it, it was the database that was missing the user id into the evaluations table. My bad...

Comment: then, you can close this question

Comment: How do I close my question?